# Where can the devices.txt file be found in Linux?

Tags: drivers, kernel, directory

I am trying to find the kernel documentation within Linux, in particular the 'devices.txt' file which has a list of driver and device major and minor numbers, i will be needing this while using the mknod command for personal use. im not looking for an online version instead im looking for the actual file in debian.

If anyone has any idea in which directory i can find this file in please let me know.

This is what im looking for looks like: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt

Comment: You would need the source tree for whatever Ubuntu kernel you are using: `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`. then the file should be there in `Documentation/admin-guide`. (Oh, I see an answer was posted while i was doing this comment.)

Comment: @Qasim if so the one you have linked to is the file. What are you **actually** trying to achieve, because this sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Then the file you found and linked to will do just fine. And there's almost zero reason to know how to use mknod. I think I last used it in Redhat 5.2 - twenty years ago. IMHO it's absolutely no reason what so ever to know it as a normal user - it's more useful to know how `udevd` works.

Comment: @Qasim: I f you do not download the kernel source, you will not have the file. The file doesn't change often, so look at it on-line or do what I said to get it.

Comment: Yes, but it's not where I would start. I would generally start with learning the actual tools, and wen you master those it's time to learn recovery.

Comment: Use it, and google and ask here, on IRC and similar when you hit problems. Try configuring your own personal webserver, mail server, or whatever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [list you found](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt). It's part of the `linux-source` package, but should be identical to the one you linked.

Devices are managed by the Linux kernel, which is very similar in all distributions.